# Attaching webform to node

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have a question regarding the webform module. Is there a way to automatically attach a webform to a type of content? I have done something similar through adding it as a field in that content type, and making it required when creating content of that type. However, is there another way to automatically embed it into a content type?

Comment: If you add a default value to your field, isn't that automatically already? And you can hide that field in form display if you want to make it sort of read-only.

Comment: I did want to make it read-only as you said, and that worked, thank you